# Why is my If/Else statment block not executing completely?

Tags: c++

I'm doing a simple project for my CS class. The goal is to have a person input the amount of each fruit (apples, bananas, oranges) they are purchasing, and the program calculates the total and presents an invoice at the end. My Professor wants us to also include an input check, to verify that the input is a number between 0 and 100. to do this, I have this section of code.

```
string name;

int apples, oranges, bananas;
int FRUIT_MAX = 100; 
int FRUIT_MIN = 0; 
float appleCost, orangeCost, bananaCost,
    subTotal, tax, total;

cout << "Welcome to Bob's Fruits, what is your name..." << endl;
getline(cin, name);

cout << "How many apples would you like" << endl;
cin >> apples;
cout << endl;

//checking if user entered a number for apples
if (apples >= FRUIT_MIN && apples <= FRUIT_MAX)
{
    cout << "Thanks" << endl;
}
else //makes the user retype entry if invalid
{
    cout << "Please input a number thats 0 or greater than 0. " << endl;
    cin >> apples;
    cout << endl;
}

cout << "How many oranges would you like" << endl;
cin >> oranges;

    if (oranges >= FRUIT_MIN && oranges <= FRUIT_MAX) //checking to see if number is good
        cout << "Thanks" << endl;
    else //makes the user retype entry if invalid
    {
        cout << "Please input a number thats 0 or greater than 0." << endl;
        cin >> oranges;
        cout << endl;
    }

cout << "How many bananas would you like" << endl;
cin >> bananas;

    if (bananas >= FRUIT_MIN && bananas <= FRUIT_MAX)
        cout << "Thanks";
    else
    {
        cout << "Please input a number thats 0 or greater than 0."; 
        cin >> bananas; 
        cout << endl;
    }
```

When I enter a value between 0-100, I receive the proper "thanks" output and then it moves on to the next question. When I enter a number outside of 0-100, the `else` statement triggers sucsessfully, and the program asks for a number between 0-11.

The problem is when a letter is input. If a letter is input, the program skips through every remaining line, ignoring any additional `cin` commands, and displays the formatted invoice with all negative numbers. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: why are you entering letter when you defined type of all your fruits of float type?

Comment: The unchecked formatted extraction you're attempting is failing. The text that caused that failure is still in the input stream, not that it matters since its failure will put the stream to disabled from future IO until you `clear()` the state. Once cleared, you need to fix the problem before trying again (i.e. get the offending bad text *out* of the input stream) or the same problem will repeat itself. In short, check your io operations. Don't assume they just worked, or that they self-heal on retry if they did not.

Comment: what if the user enters 2 invalid values in a row?

Comment: I see this quite a lot: newcomers assuming that their program just magically skips over and "ignores" "commands". It obviously will never do that, so instead you should look at the behaviour of those "commands" in the documentation and find out what conditions may lead them to have no effect. If you did so, you'd very quickly determine that an _error flag_ had been set on your stream. Then you'd be able to use that knowledge to work out how to fix your program.

Answer (score 2):

When cin gets an invalid value, it sets a failbit.

```
int n;
cin >> n;
if(!cin)
{
    //not a number, input again!
}
```

You need to use `cin.ignore()` so that the input will be 'reset' and request the input again.

Answer (score 1):

you can change the cin part into

```
while (!(cin>>apples)) {
    cout<<"Type Error"<<endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin.sync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem ist that you do not check for proper type of your input.

Your apples variable is an Int. So as long as a user enters an Int everything will be fine.

But what happens if he or she enters a Char ?
*The answer is as one of the guys before me mentioned is that the cin operation will fail.*

What can you do to prevent or better to say handle this situation:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc , char** argv)    {

    int apples = 0; //Its always good to initialise a var with a value

    cout << "Please enter a number: " << endl;
    cin >> apples;

    if(!cin) {
        cout << "Not a number!" << endl;
        // Handle the error
    }
    else  {
        cout << "A number was entered" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Instead of checking for **!cin** you can also use  **cin.fail()** which will be true if the last cin operation failed.

If you want to read more about  **cin**  or inputstreams in generell I would advise you to take a look at the [C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cin/?kw=cin).